# Login Form Module redirects not working

Tags: login, redirect, joomla-3.9

Quite new to Joomla and have a problem with Login Form Redirects
I’m using Joomla 3.9.4 / PHP 7.1.9 / Apache / mysql 5.7.22-22

I have a Landing Page using one Gantry/Helium template, all other pages use a separate single template. I have a single Login Form Module with the Login Redirect to a hidden menu item “hello” and the Logout Redirect to hidden menu item “goodbye”. Module access is Public

The hidden menu has items “hello” and “goodbye” both with access Public. In turn the menu item type is single article pointing to Hello and Goodbye respectively. The articles both use the same template and have access set to Public. If I add these to a main menu they open the articles as expected

The main menu items (Login with access Public/Logout with access Registered) are of menu type Single Article pointing to an Article called LoggingIn. This article has some text , a graphic and a {loadmoduleid 16}

The redirects do not work - Login takes me to the Logging in article and displays the text, graphic and log in form. After entering Username and Password the redirect is to a the default template but without any article displayed. Same happens on Log Out - the Logout button is displayed OK but the redirect is the same as Log In

Any assistance or ideas appreciated
Cheers

Comment: Have replicated it on a stand alone PC and it looks like a permissions problem but I can't see where

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with the Jomsocial Redirect plugin that I had not configured!
I installed a clean system and added the extensions on the live system to this test system - all worked until I added Jomsocial - quick Google then gave sufficient clues